# Python Regex: Find a json format in a string that at least has one known key:value pair

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to come up with a regex that will find a valid json string embedded in text, for example:

```
....Some generic text here....
\n
\n
{id:3, created_at:2019-12-01T00:00:00Z, closed_at:2019-12-02T00:00:00Z}
```

So there is some generic text, followed by *2* newlines and then a json string and it must always have at least `id:3` part anywhere in the json.

Here is my attempt:

```
\s\s([{].*?[}])$
```

Can't figure out how to extend this to have a mandatory `id:3` attribute.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, try it, `\s\s([{].*id:3.*[}])$`

Comment: It works nicely! How can I improve this to be more strict in terms of json structure? for example to make comma mandatory between key:value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
\s\s({.*id:3.*})$
```

This should give you 0 or more of any character, require the `id:3` portion and then 0 or more of any character again. And then it doesn't matter where the `id:3` part comes in the string.